# Flash Video on Chrome - No Video but Plays Audio

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, video, flash

I'm having an issue with flash videos on my site when viewed in Chrome.

The audio plays but no video or controls. I've played around with the wmode parameter in the embed code but with no go. Video embed code came from Brightcove where the videos are being hosted.

The video is also being viewed on an HTTPS page and found this on Brightcove:
http://support.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/docs/publishing-video-cloud-player-https-page

Embed code here:

```
    <object id='myExperience' class='BrightcoveExperience'>
  <param name='bgcolor' value='#FFFFFF' />
  <param name='width' value='480' />
  <param name='height' value='270' />
  <param name='playerID' value='2119278990001' />
  <param name='playerKey' value='AQ~~,AAABtOucX_k~,lzAbJ4EGCWOe52SAdLGfbpIpAw34U8gW'/>
  <param name='isVid' value='true' />
  <param name='isUI' value='true' />
  <param name='dynamicStreaming' value='true' />
     <param name='includeAPI' value='true' />
  <param name='@videoPlayer' value='2806424814001' />
    <param name='templateLoadHandler' value='myTemplateLoaded' />
    <param name='templateReadyHandler' value='onTemplateReady' />
    <param name='secureConnections' value='true' />
    <param name='secureHTMLConnections' value='true' />
    <param name='wmode' value='transparent' />
</object>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Whats the extension of the file that you are trying to play?

Comment: @Scrooj I believe it might be an m4v w/ an H.264 / MP4 Codec